# What are the meanings of the abbreviations used in the Hatch/Redpath Concordance to the Septuagint?

Tags: resource-request, septuagint

I bought the Hatch/Redpath concordance to the Septuagint set a little while ago. I have looked everywhere, and can't find a key to all the abbreviations and what they mean. The preface is of very little help too. Can anybody provide me with info?

Comment: Although it doesn't address the abbreviation issue, if you're having trouble navigating Hatch and Redpath more generally, we have [a helpful answer on Hermeneutics.SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/14206/3555) that provides some guidance about how to use it.

Answer (score 5):

One place to start would be with the first edition of the work, which is available on [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Concordance_to_the_Septuagint) (only the [2nd volume](https://books.google.com/books?id=CFQzAQAAMAAJ) and [supplement](https://books.google.com/books?id=_XoZAAAAYAAJ) are on Google Books). From what I can tell, the second edition closely follows the first, so the [list of abbreviations and symbols](https://books.google.com/books?id=_XoZAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=hatch+redpatch+concordance&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7w8CKyKLKAhUKdD4KHVSkCxMQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=abbreviations%20and%20symbols&f=false) (found in the supplement) should be helpful:

> [image: Greek]
>
> [image: Old Latin]

Comment: One of the sadder facts of life is that it's actually only the supplement to H-R that's available from Google Books. (If this has changed since I last looked into it please do point me in the right direction! But the link above is the supplement.) I'm not sure to what extent the abbreviation list in the supplement is comprehensive for the full volume, but, as you said, it's a good place to start, +1. :-) (The full version is [available on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Concordance_to_the_Septuagint).... maybe they share an abbreviation list?)

Comment: @Susan Google now has the 2nd volume, apparently.  I don't see any other abbreviations on Wikimedia other than this supplement page, so this may be all that's available.

Comment: oooh, exciting, thanks! That is indeed new. Ah, found a relevant statement in the preface to the supplement that seems to confirm your finding that the list is not elsewhere: `There is appended a list of the most common and less obvious abbreviations and symbols used in the whole work.` Apparently they (---> he) didn't think it was necessary on initial publication, and then people like the OP started asking questions....

Comment: Thank you so much. Am I blind, or is "Al." missing from that abbreviations list? I see it in my addition. Any ideas on what that means?

Comment: I'm also not seeing _Quint._ there. Perhaps more sources were added in the second edition?